# AWS S3 - Cached files

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, browser-cache

I am serving all the images of my webapp from a S3 Bucket. The problem is that, if I update the file via Java SDK, the website does not refresh the image due to caché.

I understand that caching is a very good thing. My problem is that I'm exposing an article catalog and images are named by their article code. For example, the article ABC101 has the image abc101.jpg; so renaming the image is not an option to me.

I don't want to beat the cache at all, only when images are updated.

How can I achieve this? Images are renewed almost daily, and users cannot see the new ones because of this problem.

Comment: How and where are they being cached? In the browser, in a proxy? Do you use `Cache-Control` or `s-maxage` headers on your images, etc.? And what is the maximum amount of time that you want your users to see the old images after you have updated them on S3?

Comment: They are being cached in the browser. See my comment on @MattHouser answer for more info. BTW I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by adding unused parameters to the urls, i.e. instead of img src="myimage.jpg", change it to myimage.jpg?v=20180223 (for example)

its likely you can automate the generation of this url 'version' number. For example for a large asp.net app I supported, we used a build number. Every time a build was pushed to production the ?v=xxxxx parameter was programmatically updated; you could customize that strategy for your particular setup.

The inclusion of the extra parameter will force the browser to request the latest image, and it will cache it until the 'version' changes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, caching of images can be a good thing: page loading will be faster, it reduces traffic, etc.

When dealing with caches, the best you can do is "recommend" to the downstream how long you want your images to be cached. But remember, there is no way for you to force them to obey your "recommendations".

So, rather than trying to "beat" the cache, you should (a) embrace the cache and use it to your advantage, and (b) change the image names when they update in S3.

1. Intentionally give your images a long lifetime in the cache by effectively using the cache headers, such as `Cache-Control`, `maxage`, `s-maxage`, etc. This will reduce page load time **when your images have not updated**.
2. When you have a new image to upload via your Java SDK, rather than overwrite the exiting image, create a new image and use that on the next page load. This way, since the image name is new, clients will be forced to download it.

However, if you're insistent on "beating" the cache, the best you can do is to give your images a very short (eg. 0 seconds) cache life using the caching headers. But if you do this, they will be downloading and re-downloading the images constantly when they have not changed.

Comment: So I understand that caching is a very good thing. My problem is that I'm exposing an article catalog and images are named by their article code. For example, the article ABC101 has the image abc101.jpg; so I can't rename the image name.

I don't want to beat the cache at all, only when images are updated.

Comment: Then the best you can do is give a short cache time. You would add these to your image when they are uploaded to S3 in their metadata. But remember the downsides I mentioned.